# How do you use #define?

Tags: c#

I'm wondering about instances when it makes sent to use #define and #if statements. I've known about it for a while, but never incorporated it into my way of coding. How exactly does this affect the compilation?

> Is #define the only thing that determines if the code is included when compiled? If I have #define DEBUGme as a custom symbol, the only way to exclude it from compile is to remove this #define statement?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In C# `#define` macros, like some of Bernard's examples, are not allowed. The only common use of `#define`/`#if`s in C# is for adding optional debug only code. For example:

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
#if DEBUG
            //this only compiles if in DEBUG
            Console.WriteLine("DEBUG")
#endif 
#if !DEBUG
            //this only compiles if not in DEBUG
            Console.WriteLine("RELEASE")
#endif
            //This always compiles
            Console.ReadLine()
        }
```

Answer (score 8):

#define is used to define compile-time constants that you can use with #if to include or exclude bits of code.

```
#define USEFOREACH

#if USEFOREACH
    foreach(var item in items)
     {  
#else
    for(int i=0; i < items.Length; ++i)
     { var item = items[i];   //take item
#endif

       doSomethingWithItem(item);
     }
```

Answer (score 3):

> Is #define the only thing that
>   determines if the code is included
>   when compiled? If I have #define
>   DEBUGme as a custom symbol, the only
>   way to exclude it from compile is to
>   remove this #define statement?

You can [undefine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkxst87d(VS.80).aspx) symbols as well

```
#if defined(DEBUG)
#undef DEBUG
#endif
```

Comment: `#if defined(X)` may not no longer be valid (at least it is not compiling for me in Visual Studio 2019, using C# 8.0!). You can still do this, just change the 1st line to `#if DEBUG`.

Answer (score 1):

Well, defines are used often for compile time constants and macros.  This can make your code a bit faster as there are really no function calls, the output values of the macros are determined at compile time.  The #if's are very useful.  The most simple example that I can think of is checking for a debug build to add in some extra logging or messaging, maybe even some debugging functions.  You can also check different environment variables this way.

Others with more C/C++ experience can add more I am sure.

Answer (score 1):

I often find myself defining some things that are done repetitively in certain functions. That makes the code much shorter and thus allows a better overview.

But as always, try to find a good measure to not create a new language out of it. Might be a little hard to read for the occasional maintenance later on.

Answer (score 1):

It's for conditional compilation, so you can include or remove bits of code based upon project attributes which tend to be:

- Intended platform (Windows/Linux/XB360/PS3/Iphone.... etc)
- Release or Debug (Generally logging, asserts etc are only included in a debug build)

They can also be used to disable large parts of a system quickly,
for example, during development of a game, I might define

```
#define PLAYSOUNDS
```

and then wrap the final call to play a sound in:

```
#ifdef PLAYSOUNDS
// Do lots of funk to play a sound
return true;
#else
return true;
```

So it's very easy for me to turn on and off the playing of sounds for a build. (Typically I don't play sounds when debugging because it gets in the way of my personal music :) )
The benefit is that you're not introducing a branch through adding an if statement....

Answer (score 0):

@Ed: When using C++, there is rarely any benefit for using #define over inline functions when creating macros. The idea of "greater speed" is a misconception. With inline functions you get the same speed, but you also get type safey, and no side-effects of preprocessor "pasting" due to the fact that parameters are evaluated before the function is called (for an example, try writing the ubiquitous MAX macro, and call it like this: MAX(x++, y).. you'll see what I'm getting at).

I have never had to use #define in my C#, and I very rarely use it for anything other that platform and compiler version checking for conditional compilation in C++.

Comment: The main use-case for `#define` is for conditional compilation (where it can be very useful). You're correct that using `#define` for symbols and (please don't do it) macros, is not a good use-case.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the most common usees of #define in C# is to differentiate between debug/release and different platforms (for example Windows and X-Box 360 in the XNA framework).