# how is #if / #endif different than if?

Tags: c#

I am following a tutorial that has this code:

```
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        int i = 1;
        while (true)
        {
#if TEST
            if (i % 2 == 0)
            continue;
#endif
            i++;
            Console.WriteLine("The value of i is {0}", i);
            if (i > 9)
                break;
            }
            Console.WriteLine("The value of i is {0}", i);

            Application.Run(new Form1());
        }
```

What is the purpose of using `#if TEST` instead of just `if(TEST)`?

Comment: Here's a related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15744/how-do-you-use-define

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's useful when you need two (or more) versions of your code with little difference. Then instead of keeping two projects using complier directives like `#if TEST` you write both versions in the same project. Then from project properties you can set value for TEST llike TEST = true and then compile the project.

```
#if TEST
    Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
#else
    Console.WriteLine("Goodbye World!");
#endif
```

If **TEST = true** it's like you just write : `Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");` and vice versa.

Answer (score 24):

Because using `#IF` will determine if the code is compiled or not.

Using `if` will determine if the code is executed or not.

It seems there's an "environment" TEST that's defined in compile time. So if that environment exists, the

```
if (i % 2 == 0)
continue;
```

will be tested and executed: Only odd numbers will be printed.

The important thing to notice is that the compiled code changes depending on the existence of `TEST`. In a "NON-TEST environment" the

```
if (i % 2 == 0)
continue;
```

won't even exist when the application is executed.

> what is the purpose of using #IF TEST instead of just if(TEST)?

`TEST` is not a variable, nor a constant. It doesn't even exist at run time. It is a flag passed to the compiler so it can decide on compiling some code (i.e putting it into the executable)

Maybe it would be clearer if the `#if` directive had something else  inside. Let's modify your snippet to this:

```
#if TEST
            if (i == 5)
                System.exit(1)//Not a c# programmer;
#endif
```

In this case, under the existence of `TEST`, the program will only loop 5 times. On each iteration, `i` will be tested against `5`. Wait a minute! **It won't even compile**!

If `TEST` is not defined, then the application will continue until another exit condition is reached. No comparison of `i` against `5` will be made.
Read more on directives [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4y6tbswk.aspx):

> #if, along with the #else, #elif, #endif, #define, and #undef directives, lets you include or
> exclude code based on the existence of
> one or more symbols. This can be
> useful when compiling code for a debug
> build or when compiling for a specific
> configuration.

Answer (score 5):

These are for compiler constants, for example:

```
#if DEBUG
  Debug.WriteLine("This is written in debug mode");
#endif
```

If the `DEBUG` constant is defined, that code gets compiled, if it's not then it's stripped out, ignored by the compiler..it's a way to determine what's in a certain build type, and stripped out for another.

It's *usually* used for additional debug type statements, but it's extensible enough to have many applications, testing code in your case.

Answer (score 2):

It means that if you have defined the preprocessor variable `TEST` and it has a non-zero value, the code will be compiled into the resulting program. You can define `TEST` by putting

```cs
#define TEST 1
```

into your program before the `#if` statement to have that code compiled in.

`if(TEST)` will expand into `if(1)` if you defined `TEST` as above.

Comment: Not quite - this is C#, which doesn't have a preprocessor and doesn't allow you to #define values like that. You can, however, define symbols as part of your compilation settings, in which case `#if TEST` acts like `#ifdef TEST` in C/C++.

Comment: Hmm...that # kinda looks like a ++ at such a small font size :)

Answer (score 1):

From [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/preprocessor-directives/preprocessor-if):

> When the C# compiler encounters an `#if` directive, followed eventually by an #endif directive, it compiles the code between the directives only if the specified symbol is defined
>
> ...
>
> The `#if` statement in C# is Boolean and only tests whether the symbol has been defined or not.

Answer (score 1):

What you're seeing is Macro language that is written for the compiler. If the compiler is working in `TEST` mode, it will include the lines

```
if (i % 2 == 0)
continue;
```

else it won't.

These values are often defined in the properties of your project. Just right-click your project and select "Properties", then "Compilation" (working from memory, here ;) )