# How do I set a #define for each file?

Tags: c#, c-preprocessor

What exactly is the purpose of #define in C#?

I currently develop an application using the ShareFile .NET API from https://github.com/citrix/ShareFile-NET

However, the samples don't run because the function which I want to call is in this block:

```
 #if Async

 #endif
```

I know I can do

```
 #define Async
```

at the top of the files, but do I have to do this for every file which has functions in this #if block? What's the purpose of this?

Comment: they are named [Preprocessor directives](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ed8yd1ha.aspx).

Comment: Thanks, I think the answer lead me on the right way

Comment: This is _not_ a duplicate of [How do you use #define?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15744/how-do-you-use-define), that duplicate was proposed by @Tinwor for the old title of this question. Please read the entire question before close-voting as duplicate.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> do I have to do this for every file?

No. You can pass [symbols](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yt3yck0x.aspx) ("defines") to the compiler. Using Visual Studio, you can set that on the project level, at `Project -> Properties -> Build -> Conditional compilation symbols`.

Using the command-line C# compiler (csc) you use the /define: flag, and when using other IDEs or compilers, see their documentation.